# Disable submit button when form text input is empty

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

i have a modal that pops up when you need to report a word in my web app, looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8HdU.jpg).

I also have [a modal that shows up after you press the Submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgIIA.jpg) and tells you the report was made successfully. (both modals are made using Bootstrap 5.0)

You cant submit the form if no word is written, becouse text input is required in order to submit, however, even if there is no word inside the text input, the second modal will show up anyways (becouse i have it binded on the submit button aswell).

After some research, i think the best way to solve this is to disable the submit button until text input is filled, but all i find are jQuery answers and i do not know jQuery.

Any JavaScript alternatives? I am trying to find something simple since the form only haves 1 input.

Thanks in advance, i am reading with atention your thoughts about this :)

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="col-1"></div>
                      <h5 class="col-9 modal-title text-center" id="modalTitle">
                        &#9888;&#65039; Reportar &#9888;&#65039;
                      </h5>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        class="btn-close col-1"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"
                      ></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                      &#128465;&#65039; ¿Sobra alguna palabra? ¡Envíamela para
                      eliminarla! &#128465;&#65039;
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pb-4">
                      <div class="col"></div>
                      <div class="col-10">
                        <form
                          spellcheck="false"
                          method="POST"
                          action="/report"
                          id="reportForm"
                        >
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            required
                            autocomplete="off"
                            name="reportedWord"
                            maxlength="30"
                            class="form-control px-2 text-center"
                          />
                          <button
                            type="submit"
                            class="form-control buttonhover mt-3"
                            data-bs-target="#reportConfirm"
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                          >
                            <svg
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              width="24"
                              height="24"
                              fill="currentColor"
                              class="bi bi-check-lg"
                              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                            >
                              <path
                                d="M12.736 3.97a.733.733 0 0 1 1.047 0c.286.289.29.756.01 1.05L7.88 12.01a.733.733 0 0 1-1.065.02L3.217 8.384a.757.757 0 0 1 0-1.06.733.733 0 0 1 1.047 0l3.052 3.093 5.4-6.425a.247.247 0 0 1 .02-.022Z"
                              />
                            </svg>
                          </button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div
                class="modal fade"
                id="reportConfirm"
                data-bs-backdrop="static"
                tabindex="-1"
                aria-labelledby="reportConfirm"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="col modal-title text-center" id="modalTitle">
                        &#10084;&#65039; Gracias por el Feedback
                        &#10084;&#65039;
                      </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                      &#128640; Tu reporte ha sido registrado correctamente
                      &#128640;
                    </div>

                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col-10"></div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Then, i am running a setTimeout to refresh the page after 3 seconds from submitting

```js
let reportRedirect = function reportRedirect() {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "/";
  }, 3000);
};
```

Besides that js code, i have no more JS, all the front end is built with Bootstrap. Backend is handled using NodeJs and Express

---

Found the solution. Removed Bootstrap modal togglers in the HTML document and wrote this code:

```js
let reportRedirect = function reportRedirect() {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "/";
  }, 3000);
};

let submitButton = document.getElementById("reportSubmit"); // Assign submit button to a variable
let ele = document.getElementById("reportForm"); // Assign form to a variable

// callback function that does :
// 1. Return the attributes who trigger the second modal to the button
// 2. Add a click() Since we have to click 2 times to display the second modal 
// (the click user does just returns the attributes to the element)
// 3. refreshes the page after 3 seconds

let enableModal = function enableModal() {
  submitButton.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
  submitButton.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "modal");
  submitButton.click();
  reportRedirect();
};

// this one (credits to @Unmitigated) checks for the submit event.
// if the form is submitted then we apply enableModal()


if (ele.addEventListener) {
  ele.addEventListener("submit", enableModal, false); //Modern browsers
} else if (ele.attachEvent) {
  ele.attachEvent("onsubmit", enableModal); //Old IE
}
```

Comment: Please provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: True, forgot about sharing the code, it will be easier like that

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the submit event on the form instead.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  console.log('submitted, show success modal');
  e.preventDefault(); // for demonstration 
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have several forms on the ejs document, i am trying to use the code you gave me using getElementById instead QuerySelector, but it is not working.

Im very new to JS DOM, barely touched it yet, could you do some insight on it pleas?

Comment: @Yellow Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry, im kinda new to stack overflow aswell, i just posted my code in the OP

Comment: @Yellow My solution here is attaching a submit event listener to the form instead of a click event listener on the button, and showing the success modal in the submit event handler. Does that work for you?

Comment: I will give it a try, as i told you i am still learning a lot of DOM concepts since until now i was studying JavaScript basics. 

By using a submit event listener you mean removing the onclick attribute on the button and replacing it for JavaScript code right?

Comment: @Yellow Yes, remove the click handler for the button and just use the code above.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends if your in a form or if you have a text box and a button

if you had a form what you could do is

```
<form onSubmit = "Submit_function();">
  <input type="text" id = "form_text">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
function Submit_function(){
if(document.getElementById('form_text') != ""){
   //your code
}
else{
   Alert("No text given");
}}
```

if you were to have an actual button rather than a form it would look very similar as you could basically use the same method, for example

```
<input type = "text" id = "text_input">
<button onClick = "Submit_function">
```

```
function Submit_function(){
if(document.getElementById('text_input') != ""){
   //your code
}
else{
   Alert("No text given");
}}
```

there are other methods you could use however for example instead of running the function when the button is pressed you could be checking if the button is pressed from javascript which would be

```
<form id = "form">
  <input type="text" id = "form_text">
  <button id = "Submit_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
var submit_btn = document.getElementById("Submit_button");


submit_btn.addEventListner("click", function(){
if(document.getElementById('form_text') != ""){
   //your code
}
else{
   Alert("No text given");
}});
```

of course like I did above you could apply the same to a button but it's pretty self explanatory

```
<input type="text" id = "form_text">
<button id = "Submit_button">Submit</button>
```

```
var submit_btn = document.getElementById("Submit_button");


submit_btn.addEventListner("click", function(){
if(document.getElementById('form_text') != ""){
   //your code
}
else{
   Alert("No text given");
}});
```

however I don't see why you wouldn't use a form as it is way better in this case.

Comment: The form structure is like this (inside a modal)
`<form method="post" action="/X">
<input type="text" required>
<button type="submit"> // this button actually triggers the second modal
`

The thing is button should be disabled when no text inside the text input, otherwise, even if the form is not submitting, the confirmation modal will show anyways.

Comment: DIdn't realize that's what he wanted to do, thank's for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Removed Bootstrap modal togglers in the HTML document and wrote this code:

```js
let reportRedirect = function reportRedirect() {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "/";
  }, 3000);
};

let submitButton = document.getElementById("reportSubmit"); // Assign submit button to a variable
let ele = document.getElementById("reportForm"); // Assign form to a variable

// callback function that does :
// 1. Return the attributes who trigger the second modal to the button
// 2. Add a click() Since we have to click 2 times to display the second modal 
// (the click user does just returns the attributes to the element)
// 3. refreshes the page after 3 seconds

let enableModal = function enableModal() {
  submitButton.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
  submitButton.setAttribute("data-bs-dismiss", "modal");
  submitButton.click();
  reportRedirect();
};

// this one (credits to @Unmitigated) checks for the submit event.
// if the form is submitted then we apply enableModal()


if (ele.addEventListener) {
  ele.addEventListener("submit", enableModal, false); //Modern browsers
} else if (ele.attachEvent) {
  ele.attachEvent("onsubmit", enableModal); //Old IE
}
```